# How to stop unwanted splits in excerpts when using shortcodes for sliders or players

Tags: shortcode, excerpt, embed, slideshow, split

Am using this code in functions.php: [Issue with enabling formatting in excerpts in Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/issue-with-enabling-formatting-in-excerpts-in-wordpress)

to allow shortcodes, javascript and formatting in the excerpt - works great, thanks.

However, I am also using a slider (slideshow satellite), which breaks if I set my excerpt length too low (the slideshow size is obviously related to its content). Does anyone know a way to keep the excerpt length low but when a post has a player/slider called by shortcode, make sure it finishes the embedded code, no matter how long it is?

Thanks

functions.php:

```
function better_trim_excerpt($text)
{
$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    $text = get_the_content('');
    //$text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);


    // Enable formatting in excerpts - Add HTML tags that you want to be parsed in excerpts, default is 55
    //$text = strip_tags($text, '<strong><b><em><i><a><code><kbd><img>');

    // Set custom excerpt length - number of words to be shown in excerpts
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 900);

    // Modify excerpt more string at the end from [...] to ...
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '...');

    $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
        array_pop($words);
        $text = implode(' ', $words);




        // IMPORTANT! Prevents tags cutoff by excerpt (i.e. unclosed tags) from breaking formatting
        $text = force_balance_tags( $text );

        $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
    } else {
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
}
return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}

// Remove the native excerpt function, and replace it with our improved function
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'better_trim_excerpt');
```

Slideshow satellite default.php:

```
<?php
global $satellite_init_ok;
if (!empty($slides)) :

$style = $this->get_option('styles');
$images = $this->get_option('Images');
$imagesbox = $images['imagesbox'];
$pagelink = $images['pagelink'];
$textloc = $this->get_option('textlocation');
$responsive = $this->get_option('responsive');
$respExtra = (isset($respExtra)) ? $respExtra : 0;
$align = $this->get_option('align');
if (!$frompost) {
    $this->Gallery->loadData($slides[0]->section);
    $sidetext = $this -> Gallery -> capLocation($this->Gallery->data->capposition,$slides[0]->section);
}
?>


<?php if ($frompost) : ?>

    <!-- =======================================
    THE ORBIT SLIDER CONTENT 
    ======================================= -->
    <div class="orbit-default
            <?php echo($this->get_option('thumbnails_temp') == 'Y') ? ' default-thumbs' : ''; ?>
            <?php echo($align) ? ' satl-align-' . $align : ''; ?>
            <?php echo($responsive) ? ' resp' : ''; ?>
         ">
        <div id="featured<?php echo $satellite_init_ok; ?>"> 
            <?php foreach ($slides as $slider) :
                $thumbnail_link = wp_get_attachment_image_src($slider->ID, 'thumbnail', false);
                $attachment_link = get_attachment_link($slider->ID);

                $class= ($images['position'] == "S") ? "stretchCenter" : "absoluteCenter";

                echo "<div class='sorbit-wide ".$class."'  
                        data-caption='#post-{$slider->ID}' 
                        data-thumb='{$thumbnail_link[0]}'>";

                $this->render('display-image', 
                  array('frompost'  =>  true,
                        'slider'    => $slider), true, 'orbit');?>

        </div>

            <?php $this -> render('display-caption', 
                    array(  'frompost'   => true, 
                            'slider'     => $slider, 
                            'fontsize'   => null,
                            'style'      => $style,
                            'i'          => null
                            ), true, 'orbit');?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div> <!-- end featured -->

    </div>
    <?php $this -> render('jsinit', array('gallery'=>false,'frompost' => true,'respExtra' => 0), true, 'orbit');?>

    <!--  CUSTOM GALLERY -->
<?php else : ?>  
    <div class="orbit-default
    <?php echo($this->get_option('thumbnails_temp') == 'Y') ? ' default-thumbs' : ''; ?>
            <?php echo($sidetext) ? ' text-' . $sidetext : ''; ?>
            <?php echo($align) ? ' satl-align-' . $align : ''; ?>
            <?php echo($responsive) ? ' resp' : ''; ?>
         ">
        <div id="featured<?php echo $satellite_init_ok; ?>"> 
            <?php $i = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($slides as $slider) : ?>     
                <?php

            $class= ($images['position'] == "S") ? "stretchCenter" : "absoluteCenter";

            echo "<div id='satl-custom-{$this->Gallery->data->id}{$slider->id}' class='sorbit-wide ".$class."' 
                data-caption='#custom{$satellite_init_ok}-$i'
                data-thumb='{$this->Html->image_url($this->Html->thumbname($slider->image))}'>";

                $this->render('display-image', 
                  array('frompost'  =>false,
                        'slider'    => $slider), true, 'orbit');?>

            </div>
        <?php
        if ($sidetext != ( "Disabled" )) :
            if ($slider->textlocation != "N") :
                ?>
                    <?php $this -> render('display-caption', 
                          array(  'frompost'   => false, 
                                  'slider'     => $slider, 
                                  'fontsize'   => $this->Gallery->data->font,
                                  'style'      => $style,
                                  'i'          => $i
                                  ), true, 'orbit');?>

                <?php else : ?>
                    <span class="sattext-none" id='custom<?php echo ($satellite_init_ok . '-' . $i); ?>'>
                    </span>
            <?php
            endif;
        endif;
        $i = $i + 1;
    endforeach;
    ?>
    </div>

    </div>
    <?php $this -> render('jsinit', array('gallery'=>$slides[0]->section,'frompost' => false, 'respExtra' => $respExtra), true, 'orbit');?>
<?php
endif;
/*     * ****** PRO ONLY ************* */
if (SATL_PRO && $this->get_option('keyboard') == 'Y') {
    require SATL_PLUGIN_DIR . '/pro/keyboard.html';
}

endif;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `min-height` in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Add `remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'bwp_trim_excerpt');`, or whatever you've named your callback, just before the slideshow runs and add it back after.

Without the actual code for both your callback and the slider I don't think I can do better.

Comment: Thanks @toscho but its not the height - I get a window and a spinning wheel but can stop the excerpt before loading all the code including js.

Removing the filter didn't work either - I'm a noob but i think that's the wrong way to go.

If its any help, my working page is http://www.thorpedene.southend.sch.uk. The slideshows are currently working because my excerpt length is set to 900

Thanks for all the help

Comment: See the last sentence of the answer-- post the code. If you do that I will edit the answer with more detail.